# How to find similarity score between two rows in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, similarity, sentence-similarity

I want to find the similarity of given sentences between two rows.

In my sample data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [f'Sent {str(i)}' for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Sentences'])
```

```
  Sentences
0    Sent 0
1    Sent 1
2    Sent 2
3    Sent 3
4    Sent 4
5    Sent 5
6    Sent 6
7    Sent 7
8    Sent 8
9    Sent 9
```

I want to find the similarity score between every two sentences for n number of sentences.

Approach #1: Create two new columns, the first one is containing each sentence copied n times (n is the total number of sentences), this creates a row of length $n^2$. The second column would be all the sentences copied n times as well (but in groups) still creating $n^2$ rows.
From here I can get the similarities and put them in just one column.

Approach #2: Create a loop that would iterate over the sentences and create the total $nC2$ similarity scores. (for now I don't know how to do this)

How to do approach #2? Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: As a similarity calculation probably cannot be vectorized, you will have to loop anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['ABC', 'ABCD', 'DEF', 'GHI']})

# set up empty array
a = np.zeros((len(df), len(df)))

# compute difference for each unique pair and assign upper triangle
a[np.triu_indices(len(df), k=1)] = [SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
                                    for a,b in combinations(df['col'], r=2)]

# complete lower diagonaltriangle and diagonal
a += a.T
np.fill_diagonal(a, 1)

# convert to DataFrame
out = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=df['col'].values, index=df['col'].values).round(2)
```

Output:

```
       ABC  ABCD   DEF  GHI
ABC   1.00  0.86  0.00  0.0
ABCD  0.86  1.00  0.29  0.0
DEF   0.00  0.29  1.00  0.0
GHI   0.00  0.00  0.00  1.0
```